# Creating pairs from different Tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Find below a Team list, and 2 Tuples devTuple and baTuple. I would like to create a Python new Tuple pairing Dev and BA from tuples. Dev & BA should belong to the same team

```
teamlist = ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5"]
devTuple = (
  1, "Dev1", "T1",
  2, "Dev2", "T2",
  3, "Dev3", "T3",
  4, "Dev4", "T3",
  5, "Dev5", "T1",
  6, "Dev6", "T3",
  7, "Dev7", "T3"
)
baTuple = (
  1, "BA1", "T1",
  2, "BA2", "T2",
  3, "BA3", "T3",
  4, "BA4", "T3",
  5, "BA4", "T3",
  6, "BA4", "T1",
  7, "BA4", "T1",
  8, "BA4", "T2"
)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store dev and ba as an array of tuples?

Comment: Also given that it's a single continuous tuple and not a tuple of tuples, are we guaranteed that every three elements is a meaningful group?

Comment: @HenryEcker QWERTL, goal is that I need to have a list of Dev BA pair without repeating the same DEV and BA from same team. We can store BA and DEV in as array as well. I just wanted to simplify my question for better understanding

Comment: @SriChin can you please end your question to _show_ what the expected output looks like?

Answer (score 1):

given your input definition, here is an approach that yields a dictionary using the team as a key and a list of players per team

```
def joinOnTeams(at, bt):
    rslt = dict()
    def loadDict(t):
        for i in range(2, len(t), 3):
            tl = rslt.pop(t[i], [])
            tl.append(t[i-1])
            rslt[t[i]] = tl

    loadDict(at)
    loadDict(bt)
    return rslt
```

Then executing `joinOnTeams(devTuple, baTuple)`, yields:

```
{'T3': ['Dev3', 'Dev4', 'Dev6', 'Dev7', 'BA3', 'BA4', 'BA4'],
 'T1': ['Dev1', 'Dev5', 'BA1', 'BA4', 'BA4'],
 'T2': ['Dev2', 'BA2', 'BA4']}
```